# Labelling a graph in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, label, edges

I am trying to build a graph with networkx, using nodes as class objects.
I have already labelled the nodes, but I am not being able to show labeled edges (actually, not edges at all). I was expecting to do so by defining the neighbouring nodes inside the Node class.
I show my code below:

```
# Packages

import random as rd
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Classes

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.state = rd.choice([-1, 0, 1])
        self.neighbour = None

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_state(self):
        return self.state
    def get_neighbour(self):
        return self.neighbour

# Nodes and neighbours

n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)

n1.neighbour = n2
n2.neighbour = n3

# Graph

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node(n1.name)
G.add_node(n2.name)
G.add_node(n3.name)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
#nx.draw_spectral(G, with_labels=True)   # I also tried this suggestion, but unsuccessfully

plt.savefig('jupyter_graph.png')
```

The reason for the "state" attribute is because I want to change the colours of the nodes depending on their state (that's another issue).
The output is below:

[image]

No edges appear. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `networkx` package does not create the graph based on the attributes in your `Node` class. The reason the values are displayed is that you pass them when adding a new node into the graph with `G.add_node(n1.name)`. Similarly in order to add edges you need to call to call the `add_edge` method. Please refer to the [tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html)